# Possible trivial counterexample to exam question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So doing an exam question for set theory this was the question:

Let X be a set. Prove there is no injection $f : P(X) → X.$

Would X being an empty set be a counter example because in this case the powerset is a set of a single element $\{\}$ hence it is mapped to a null element.

However would this be the case that $f$ would not be a function, since there isn't $(a,b)\in f$ hence $f$ isn't defined for the whole of the domain hence $f$ is not a function.

So yes I understand that this isn't a proof for this problem but while thinking about the problem I was trying some examples and non-examples and couldn't work out why this failed until I actually put it into words.

Sorry for a convoluted question, I don't really have the correct notation to explain myself.

Comment: The problem is to prove "There is no such a thing" instead of finding a counterexample :).

Comment: What you have outlined is the argument for $X = \emptyset$.  The question, however, asks you to prove that such an injection does not exist for *any* $X$.

Comment: $P(X)$ is never the empty set because it has at least one member, namely $X$. Since $P(X)$ is not empty , if $X$ is empty then there is no function $f:P(X) \to X$ of any kind so there is certainly no injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $X=\varnothing$ is not a counterexample. You seem to have realized (though your wording is a bit strange) that there *is no function* $\mathcal P(\varnothing)\to\varnothing$ -- so in particular there is no *injective* function, so we have seen that the claim *is true* for $X=\varnothing$.

(A "counterexample" means an example that makes the claim *false*).

---

Any course that has exam questions of this kind will probably have proved the celebrated

> **Cantor's Theorem.** Let $X$ be a set. No function $X\to\mathcal P(X)$ can be surjective.

So one strategy would be to show that *if* there were an injection $\mathcal P(X)\to X$ you could construct a surjection $X\to \mathcal P(X)$.

Another way would be to combine the assumed injection $\mathcal P(X)\to X$ with the obvious injection $X\to\mathcal P(X)$, so the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem would conclude that there is a *bijection* $X\to\mathcal P(X)$, which again contradicts Cantor's theorem.

Comment: Yeah so the issue is not with the question but with if X is an empty set what is the implications of that with respect to this question, however please correct me if I am incorrect but if X is an empty set then f is not a function?

Comment: @Cjen1: It would be more precise to say that if $X=\varnothing$ then _there are no functions $\mathcal P(X)\to X$ at all_ to begin with -- so whatever $f$ means to you, it will not be such a function. (Just edited the answer to say this too).

Answer (score 1):

One can "dualise" the proof of Cantor's theorem to the present situation:

If $f:\>{\cal P}(X) \to X$ is injective with image set $P\subset X$ then we have a well defined  inverse map $f^{-1}:\>P\to{\cal P}(X)$. Consider the "special" set $A:=\{x\in P\,|\, x\notin f^{-1}(x)\}$, and put $a:=f(A)\in P$. Then it is easy to check that one has
$$a\in A\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a\notin f^{-1}(a)=A\ ,$$
which is absurd.